# VBS, creating full hierarchy string from parent-child structure, recursion

Tags: vbscript, parent-child

I am trying to do a following in Visual basic script. There is a hierarchy of elements, I have the lowest element (base) and I need to create full hierarchy string . I have a function, which returns parents of an element. That means I can ask for a parent, then parents of the parent, etc.

Example: B is Parent of A, C1, C2 are parents of B, ...

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pg2D.png)

In this example, the result should be array of 3 strings (lines 1,2,3), each containing the full hierarchy for the base element A.

I've tried for loops, but somehow i cant to put is together. I am not VBS expert and array handling looks pretty clumsy to me. Any tips?

EDIT:

This is my current function:

```
Function GetAllParents (strServer, strDimension, strElem)
    
    dim strPath     
    dim strElement
    dim strParent
    dim lngCount 
    dim i
    dim j
    dim k
    dim result
    result = strElem
    strElement = strElem
    lngCount = AleaElement.ElementParentsCount (strServer, strDimension, strElement)
    
    if (lngCount > 0) then
        for i = 1 to lngCount       
            strParent = AleaElement.ElementParentsName(strServer, strDimension, strElement, i)
            result = result & "  " & GetAllParents(strServer, strDimension, strParent) 
        next 
    end if
    GetAllParents = result

End Function
```

This is The result I get:

```
CST_700P36 CST_AM_FAE_1002 CST_RM_FAE_NRTH1 CST_OM_FAE_NRTH CST_RET_SAS_RD1 CST_RET_SAS_MNGMT CST_RETAIL_DIVN CST_TOTAL
CST_TOTAL_I&E 
CST_SS_FAE_CUR CST_SS_FAE CST_RET_SAS CST_RET_SAR CST_RETAIL_DIVN CST_TOTAL 
CST_TOTAL_I&E 
CST_RET_SAS_EX_VIR 
CST_RETAIL_ALL CST_RETAIL CST_ALL_COST
```

this is the result I need:

```
CST_700P36 CST_AM_FAE_1002 CST_RM_FAE_NRTH1 CST_OM_FAE_NRTH CST_RET_SAS_RD1 CST_RET_SAS_MNGMT CST_RETAIL_DIVN CST_TOTAL
CST_700P36 CST_AM_FAE_1002 CST_RM_FAE_NRTH1 CST_OM_FAE_NRTH CST_RET_SAS_RD1 CST_RET_SAS_MNGMT CST_RETAIL_DIVN CST_TOTAL_I&E
CST_700P36 CST_AM_FAE_1002 CST_RM_FAE_NRTH1 CST_OM_FAE_NRTH CST_SS_FAE_CUR CST_SS_FAE CST_RET_SAS CST_RET_SAR CST_RETAIL_DIVN CST_TOTAL 
CST_700P36 CST_AM_FAE_1002 CST_RM_FAE_NRTH1 CST_OM_FAE_NRTH CST_SS_FAE_CUR CST_SS_FAE CST_RET_SAS CST_RET_SAR CST_RETAIL_DIVN CST_TOTAL_I&E 
CST_700P36 CST_AM_FAE_1002 CST_RM_FAE_NRTH1 CST_OM_FAE_NRTH CST_SS_FAE_CUR CST_RET_SAS_EX_VIR 
CST_700P36 CST_RETAIL_ALL CST_RETAIL CST_ALL_COST
```

It looks like the once included parts are not put in again.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This looks like a candidate for [recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314799/recursion-issues-with-vbscript/11355885).

Comment: @Rno yeah figured the same, added current results