# Creating full hierarchy string from parent-child structure algorithm, recursion

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I am solving following task. There is a given hierarchy of elements. I have the lowest element (base) and I need to create full hierarchy string. I have a function, which returns parents of an element. That means I can ask for a parent, then parents of the parent, etc.

Example: B is Parent of A, [C1, C2] are parents of B, ...

[image: Example]

In this example, the result should be array of 3 strings (lines 1,2,3), each containing the full hierarchy for the base element A.

This is my pseudocode function:

```
Function getAllParents (Element)

    ParentCount = getParentCount(Element)
    result = Element
    IF (ParentCount > 0) THEN
        FOR i = 0 to ParentCount
            ParentName = getParentName(Element, i)
            result =  result + "," + getAllParents(parent)
        NEXT
    END IF
    
    IF (ParentCount = 0) then       
        result =  result + &newLine
    END IF
    
    RETURN result

END Function
```

It gives me following result for my example:

```
A,B,C1,D1,E1 
C2,D2,E2  
E3
```

How to achieve desired result?:

```
A,B,C1,D1,E1
A,B,C2,D2,E2
A,B,C2,D2,E3
```

Comment: what do you mean it gives you? are you running it somehow? it's *pseudo*-code, no? second, _how_ are you running it? i.e. what's the (imaginary) call you're making? third, imagine you call `getAllParents(E1)`. `ParentCount` is 0. the loop is void. so you just execute `result =  result + &newLine`, but what *is* this `result` to which you're appending the `newLine`?

Comment: @WillNess this is generalized question to my original language specific [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67075109/vbs-creating-full-hierarchy-string-from-parent-child-structure-recursion) . I've added the missing line initializing the result: result = Element. I call this function for base elements only, there is always a parent.

Comment: The variable, `parent`, does not seem to be declared in your pseudocode.

Answer (score 1):

We must build the current `line` on the way in, and join the returned lines together as the `result` on the way out from the recursion. Here is a pseudo code :

```
Function getAllParents (line, Element)
    result = “”
    ParentCount = getParentCount(Element)
    IF (ParentCount > 0) THEN
        FOR i = 0 to ParentCount
            ParentName = getParentName(Element, i)
            result_i = getAllParents(copy(line)+”,”+ParentName, ParentName)
            result = result + result_i
        NEXT
    ELSE
        result = copy(line)+&newLine
    END IF
    
    RETURN result

END Function
```

A `newline` is added to the `line` each time a terminal node is reached, just like in your table.

We call it as `getAllParents( “A”, “A”)`.

To better understand how it works, here is the function call flow for your example :

```
(“A”, “A”)
- (“A,B”, “B”)
- - (“A,B,C1”, “C1”)
- - - (“A,B,C1,D1”, “D1”)
- - - - (“A,B,C1,D1,E1”, “E1”)
- - (“A,B,C2”, “C2”)
- - - (“A,B,C2,D2”, “D2”)
- - - - (“A,B,C2,D2,E2”, “E2”)
- - - - (“A,B,C2,D2,E3”, “E3”)
```

Comment: instead of `Element = lastWordOf(line)`, pass 2 arguments to the recursive call. augment the top call accordingly. `line_i` can contain multiple lines in it, better call it `result_i`. lastly, some explanations, with words, would be beneficial / are in order. in particular, the change is much more than "just memorize the ...". it in fact flips the whole direction in which the result is getting built -- it introduces the fresh `result` for each new recursive call instead of trying to build it on the way back from recursion, and passes the result-prefix-so-far on the way *into* the recursion.

Answer (score 0):

As you said yourself in the question description, the issue is the result type: "the result should be array."

Here's an example in JavaScript:

```js
function getParentCount(el, ps){
  return ps[el] && ps[el].length
}

function getParentName(el, i, ps){
  return ps[el][i]
}
    
function getAllParents(el, ps){
  const ParentCount = getParentCount(el, ps)
  
  const result = []
  
  if (ParentCount > 0){
    for (let i=0; i<ParentCount; i++){
      const ParentName = getParentName(el, i, ps)
      const ParentPaths = getAllParents(ParentName, ps)
      
      for (let path of ParentPaths)
        result.push(el + "," + path)
    }
        
  } else {
    result.push(el)
  }
  
  return result
}

const parents = {
  A: ['B'],
  B: ['C1', 'C2'],
  C1: ['D1'],
  C2: ['D2'],
  D1: ['E1'],
  D2: ['E2', 'E3']
}

for (let path of getAllParents('A', parents))
  console.log(path)
```

Comment: but that's not what was asked. they wanted one string as a result, with newlines separating the paths.

Comment: @WillNess no, they didn't: "In this example, the result should be array of 3 strings (lines 1,2,3), each containing the full hierarchy for the base element A."

Comment: ah OK, I interpreted "array" metaphorically, as "several items", I guess, looking at the code.

Comment: @WillNess that would be literature.stackexchange.com :)

Comment: people do use language in imprecise ways sometimes. :) their literal words said one thing, their code said another...

Comment: @WillNess I know, I'm just teasing.